# Pass Id column in jQuery data tables as parameter?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, parameters, jquery-data

I have build a table with jQuery Data tables, and i would like a the button to preform a function.

So far i can get the buttons to enter the jquery function but they always pass though the parameter null.

I am trying to pass the GoodNumberId to the function.

```
function GetGoods() {

        $.post("GetGoods", function (GoodsDS) {
            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(GoodsDS);
            var table = obj.Table;

            $('#demo').html('<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example"></table>');
            $('#TableWrapper').dataTable({
                "bJQueryUI": true,
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                "bProcessing": true,
                "bDeferRender": true,
                "aaData": table
             ,
                "aoColumns": [
                { "mDataProp": "GoodNumberId", "sTitle": "Goods ID" },
                { "mDataProp": "SerialNumber", "sTitle": "Serial Number" },
                { "mDataProp": "Make", "sTitle": "Make" },
                { "mDataProp": "Model", "sTitle": "Model" },
                { "mDataProp": "Description", "sTitle": "Description" },
                //{ "mDataProp": "IMEINumber", "sTitle": "IMEINumber" },
                { "mDataProp": "Condition", "sTitle": "Condition" },
               // { "mDataProp": "DistinguishingMarks", "sTitle": "DistinguishingMarks" },
               // { "mDataProp": "OtherFeatures", "sTitle": "OtherFeatures" },
                //{ "mDataProp": "Status", "sTitle": "Status" },
                { "mDataProp": "ItemStatus", "sTitle": "Item Status" },
                { "mDataProp": "Price", "sTitle": "Price" },
                { "mDataProp": "TransactionDate", "sTitle": "Transaction Date" },
                //{ "mDataProp": "TransactionTypeId", "sTitle": "TransactionTypeId" },
                {"mDataProp": "TransactionDescription", "sTitle": "Transaction" },
                { "mData": null,
                    "bSortable": false,
                    "mRender": function (GoodNumberId) { return '<input id="btnDispose" type="button" onclick="Dispose(' + GoodNumberId +')" value="Dispose" />'; }
                }   
                ]
            });
        });
    };
```

The table variable looks as follows:

[image]

I need each button to pass the Id of it's current row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [mRender](http://datatables.net/ref#mRender) function takes 3 parameters:

> function - the function given will be executed whenever DataTables
>   needs to set  or get the data for a cell in the column. The function
>   takes three parameters:
>
> {array|object} The data source for the row
>   (based on mData)
>
> {string} The type call data requested - this will be
>   'filter',  'display', 'type' or 'sort'.
>
> {array|object} The full data
>   source for the row (not based on mData)

So the first parameter it takes is "based on mData".  Since your mData is null, the first parameter is null.

Try this:

```
{ 
  "mData": "GoodNumberId",
  "bSortable": false,
  "mRender": function (sourceData) 
     { return '<input id="btnDispose" type="button" onclick="Dispose(' 
           + sourceData +')" value="Dispose" />'; }
}
```

**Edit**
To include status per comments, try this:

```
{ 
  "mData": "GoodNumberId",
  "bSortable": false,
  "mRender": function (sourceData, dataType, fullData) 
     { 
        if (fullData.Status == 'Disposed') // or whatever
            return '&nbsp';
        else
            return '<input id="btnDispose" type="button" onclick="Dispose(' 
           + sourceData +')" value="Dispose" />'; }
}
```

Comment: Do you know if i could apply an if statement to show the button dependent on the Item status. Its one of the columns in the row. { "mDataProp": "Status", "sTitle": "Status" },

Comment: I think so.  Include all three parameters, like function(sourceData,dataType,fullData).  Look at fullData - I believe you'd want something like "if (fullData.Status == "

Comment: So what do i change mData to?so that i can populate FullData to do as you have shown?

Comment: Leave mData as it is.  The third parameter is "The full data source for the row (not based on mData)", so it should contain the object.  I've edited it to show how I think it should work.

Comment: Thanks i see now, just trying out the if in there now :), will let you know how it goes, thanks so much.

Comment: Wish i could give more up votes, it all works great! Thanks for the help :)